# NodeJS killed when react-native app is closed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Actually i'm new to *react* and *node* and i was trying to make a simple `NodeJS` server which return some data from `MySQL Database` but i'm having some issues with the back-end part.

Actually i've installed NodeJS in another computer and followed this [guide](https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4) to deploy it.

Then in my `React-Native` app i just do simple *fetch* call to the `NodeJS` with the ip of the computer where the back-end part is installed till here all work fine and even from my personal computer i can get the data from `NodeJS server` but i face the issue when **after loading data** in React-App i **kill that app** and then i **reopen it** after that seems the server just die and i have to restart it with command 'node myfile.js'

After killing the app, NodeJS server is impossible to reach from any device and in browser after some minutes of load just return 'PAGE DOESN'T WORK ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'

Here is routes.js file located in another PC

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'block',
  database : 'mydb'
});

// Starting our app.
const app = express();

// Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'users' table.
app.get('/prenotazioni', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'users' table).
    connection.query("SELECT Data, Importo_Doc FROM tabella_pagamenti", function (error, results, fields) {
      // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
      if (error) throw error;

      // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Vai su http://localhost:3000/prenotazioni per vedere i dati.');
});
```

While method in my react-app where i call fetch is the following

```
GetData = () => {
  return fetch('http://192.168.100.160:3000/prenotazioni')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {

    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson,
    }, function(){

    });

  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors ? you should try to release the connect after query `connection.release();` inside the callback function of your `connection.query`

Comment: @Panther actually in PowerShell i get no errors and in React-App i just get 'Network request failed'

Comment: make sure that you are handling the errors correctly, you need to `return res.end()` when you get an error

Comment: @Panther actually seems that after adding connection.release(); all work fine, make an answer so i can accept it